# Re-targeting symbolic link in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, symlink

I am using Windows XP, with ClearCase Explorer 7.0.1.0-IFIX01.

I have the following directory:

```
/vob_myvob/path/to/symlink/
```

And it is pointing to the following directory:

```
/vob_exports/path/to/third/party/dependencies/v3.4.1.0/LATEST_STABLE
```

I want to change this so that, for my "future development" branch, I use a different symlink target than all my other branches:

```
/vob_exports/path/to/third/party/dependencies/v3.4.6.0/LATEST_STABLE
```

There are a lot of breaking changes between v3.4.1 and v3.4.6, so I need complete isolation.

Are symlinks even the right approach here?  We do not have access to UCM.

Note, I am not looking to create a symbolic link.  One already exists.  I mention my OS because I have read on IBM's site that its not advised to mess with symlinks on Windows.  I can ask our admin team to do something on the UNIX side if necessary.  So far they are not very helpful, and maybe need a good pointer.

Answer (score 1):

UCM is not related to, unless you have one UCM component per third party.

I tried the symlink approach before for third parties, but unless you are talking about *source* dependencies, I have since exported all those third-party binaries out of ClearCase, and in a proper artifact repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

That way, I can version only a file *declaring* the dependencies I need (a `pom.xml` in the case of Nexus), which means a specific branch can have a version of that file declaring a dependency to 3.4.6.0, while that same file includes 3.4.1.0 in all the other branches.

That is the current best practice (i.e. use a *source* control tool to version *sources*, not binaries)

That being said, symlink (as in `cleartool ln`) can work (on Windows or Unix), with only some side-effect (like this [technote illustrates](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM04810))